# Are synthetic vitamins from drugstores far less healthy and useful than those from natural products?

Tags: nutrition, micronutrients, supplement, meal

Is it correct that vitamin supplements that are sold in drugstores in form of pills/tablets are not so useful for health than those that we get from natural food, vegetables and fruits?

Comment: Synthetic is not the correct word.  It is typically the actual vitamin in raw form.  You might not get as much absorption from the vitamin pill.  Some vitamins like potassium and magnesium are hard to get enough of in natural foods.

Comment: Might rephrase the question: Are vitamins and/or minerals in pill form more or less bio-available to humans than those from natural sources?